# How do I get my memory channel(Single channel, Dual channel, etc) type in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory

I want to know what type of my memory channel in Linux, Single or Dual or etc..

1. I try find it by check /proc filesystem, but didn't success. And then
2. I use `dmidecode` to get system informations, and check, also didn't find.

How can I get it?

Comment: The accepted answer (Interleaved Data Depth) is not correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Search the `dmidecode` output for `Interleaved Data Depth`. Dual-channel memory has an interleaved depth of 2.

Comment: What if I don't have the `Interleaved Data Depth" line at all there?

Comment: And what if I have "Interleaved Data Depth: Unknown"?

Comment: IDK whenever this is a reliable way to distinguish single vs. dual memory channel/support. Some systems will report `Unknown` while others might report `1` even though BIOS itself and other tools (i.e. CPU-Z) reports dual channel mode.

Comment: Hi, I'm using ASUS X99-E WS/USB 3.1 motherboard, but my dmidecode couldn't report any interleaved depth number. Does it mean my motherboard isn't using its quad-channel feature?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Interleaved Data Depth does not indicate the number of channels, even when it does report a number. You could be running in dual-channel and still show an Interleaved Data Depth of 1.

Answer (score 5):

People giving "Interleaved Data Depth" as the answer are not correct. Interleaved Data Depth either is not the correct indicator or is very commonly misreported (If it's reported at all).

An easy way to obtain how many channels you're using is to do something like the following:

```sh
sudo dmidecode -t 17 | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; OFS="\t" } /Size|Channel/ { line = (line ? line OFS : "") $2 } /^$/ { print line; line="RAM" }' | grep -iv 'no'
```

sample output (**Dual channel**):

```
RAM  32 GB   ChannelA-DIMM0
RAM  32 GB   ChannelB-DIMM0
```

On this same machine, let's check Interleaved Data Depth:

```sh
sudo dmidecode | grep Interleaved
```

output:

```
Interleaved Data Depth: 1
Interleaved Data Depth: 1
```

On this same machine was also verified in Windows via CPU-Z. Under memory was reported verbatim: **Dual Channel**

So Interleaved Data Depth is incorrect but we can easily check our channels (A, B, C, D, etc.).

Comment: Hmm. I still can't tell from your output *why* you know you have dual channel. Is it because `A` and `B` are both in use? On my system, the 3rd column of info is missing, and I don't understand AWK well enough to correct it.

Answer (score 3):

The channels wont tell you if it runs in dual channel mode or not, it only tells you which channel are using a memory module

Here's my output after trying to get 2x8GB + 4x4GB DIMM to work on my x79 board

```
RAM  8192 MB     ChannelA_Dimm1  ChannelA    ChannelA_Dimm1_AssetTag
RAM  4096 MB     ChannelA_Dimm2  ChannelA    ChannelA_Dimm2_AssetTag
RAM  8192 MB     ChannelB_Dimm1  ChannelB    ChannelB_Dimm1_AssetTag
RAM  4096 MB     ChannelB_Dimm2  ChannelB    ChannelB_Dimm2_AssetTag
RAM  4096 MB     ChannelD_Dimm1  ChannelD    ChannelD_Dimm1_AssetTag
```

you can't tell from that if they run in single, dual or triple channel mode.

Comment: i've compared a single ram stick laptop to a double ram stick laptop i notice the property `Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)` on the single ram stick one, and simply `Type Detail: Synchronous` on the dual ram stick one, i'm tempted to think of it as indicator of dual channel mode.......